# Delphi, TArray and array of

Tags: arrays, delphi

I know there are gazillion questions regarding conversion between different types of array in Delphi but I always forget and always get stuck in simple things.

```
procedure Proc1;
var
  a: array of string;
  b: TArray<string>;
begin
  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      a := ['aa'] + ['bb'];
      AddStrings(a); // (1) compiled normally
      AddStrings(a + ['cc']); // (2) compiled normally
      AddStrings(['cc'] + a); // (3) compiler error E2029, ')' expected but '+' found

      b := ['aa'] + ['bb'];
      AddStrings(b); // (4) compiled normally
      AddStrings(b + ['cc']); // (5) compiled normally
      AddStrings(['cc'] + b); // (6) compiler error E2029, ')' expected but '+' found

      AddStrings(['aa', 'bb']); // (7) compiled normally
      AddStrings(['aa'] + ['bb']); // (8) compiler error E2029, ')' expected but '+' found
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

Why the `AddStrings` (1,2,4,5,7) are compiled normally and (3,6,8) are not?

**Update**, as *Stefan Glienke* mentioned there is no built-in version of `AddStrings` with dynamic arrays in Alexandria (only open arrays). After some tests with the code below and changing `AddStrings` to `AddStrings2` accordingly in the main code I have got the following results:

1. If both (1-Overload) and (2-Overload) are present - tasks (3,6,8) are
   compiled
2. If only (1-Overload) is present - tasks (6,8) are compiled, (3) is not
3. If only (2-Overload) is present - all tasks (3,6,8) are not compiled. So (2-Overload) acts and looks exactly as built-in `AddStrings`.

What I don't understand is how (2-Overload) fully imitating `AddStrings` together(???) with (1-Overload) wins over the task (3).

```
type
  TStringsHelper = class helper for TStrings
    procedure AddStrings2(const values: TArray<string>); overload; // (1-Overload)
    procedure AddStrings2(const values: array of string); overload; // (2-Overload)
  end;

procedure TStringsHelper.AddStrings2(const values: TArray<string>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(values) to High(values) do
    Add(values[i]);
end;

procedure TStringsHelper.AddStrings2(const values: array of string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(values) to High(values) do
    Add(values[i]);
end;
```

Comment: What was the compiler error message?  You should include such information in a question like this.

Comment: My guess is the compiler is treating `['...']` in (3,6,8) as a `Set` instead of as a `DynArray`, since `Set` constants and `Array` constants use the same `[...]` syntax (see [Structured Types](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)) in Delphi's documentation). You can't join a `Set` and an `Array`, but you can use [`System.Concat()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Concat) to join two `Array`s together, if needed.

Comment: @Remy I suspected that such function should exist, but never met and never used before, it helped with compiling (3,6) but failed with (8). Interesting that `b := ['cc'] + b;` is compiled normally, so `['...']` is considered as an array here.

Comment: In addition to the declared variables, there are also implicit ones. For tasks 1 to 8, a result is always stored in an implicit intermediate variable. In cases 1,2,4,5,7 their type is defined. But not in cases 3,6,8.

Comment: @USauter That's possible, but I could not express it explicitly, even introducing intermediate array types didn't help. So it's just a version. Also (2,3) and (5,6) are treated differently which is weird and contradicts the common sense.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant overload of `AddStrings` is this:

```
procedure AddStrings(const Strings: array of string); overload;
```

So when the compiler sees the `[` it decides that it will treat this as passing what is within the brackets as [open array parameter](https://enter%20link%20description%20here). When it sees the `]` the parameter is done and you could either then pass the `Objects` array in the 2 parameter overload or you are done (hence the `')' expected but '+' found`).

When you put the dynamic array first, the compiler allows the `+` because it has not yet decided to pass that dynamic array as open array argument but notices that it knows how to handle the plus operator on them.

Basically, there are two language syntax pieces at conflict here: the older feature of open array parameters where you put the elements you want to pass within square brackets, and the newer dynamic array syntax that was introduced in XE7.

I would assume they could have taught the compiler to not be so eager about the square brackets and first look a bit further before assuming you are passing values as an open array argument.

Let's prove what I wrote:

```
procedure AddStrings(const values: TArray<string>);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(values) to High(values) do
    Write(values[i], ' ');
  Writeln;
end;

procedure Proc1;
var
  a, b: TArray<string>;
begin
  a := ['aa'] + ['bb'];
  AddStrings(a);
  AddStrings(a + ['cc']);
  AddStrings(['cc'] + a);
  a := ['cc'] + a;

  b := ['aa'] + ['bb'];
  AddStrings(b); 
  AddStrings(b + ['cc']);
  AddStrings(['cc'] + b);

  AddStrings(['aa', 'bb']);
  AddStrings(['aa'] + ['bb']);
end;
```

Compiles and runs fine because the compiler is now properly treating the square brackets as a dynamic array.

Now I just remembered something about this method and looked through the Embarcadero JIRA and look what I found: a ticket that says [Parameters in TStrings.AddStrings should be changed to open array](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34286) which was fixed some while ago in Delphi 11. As I wrote in the decription dynamic array parameters can cause a ton of unnecessary dynamic array allocation even if you simply write something such as `AddStrings(['aa', 'bb']);` which is just setting some pointers to some reserved stack space when it's an open array parameter.

That being said it could very well be that the code in your question compiled fine from XE7 until 10.4 and "broke" when they changed the signature.

I am sure the issue with dynamic array concatenation in an open array parameter is reported somewhere - I will update if/when I find it.

**Update**: a local variable of type `array of string` is not compatible with `TArray<string>` this is some obscure "typesafety" rule of Pascal where structurally identical types are not assignment compatible. It makes sense for records where different types might have the same binary layout but should not be assignment compatible. But in my opinion, it makes no sense that different dynamic array types although they are the same, are not assignment compatible.

You can easily see that `a` and `b` are not assignment compatible.

Apart from the better code gen, this is another reason why I usually prefer open array parameters where it makes sense.

Comment: I updated the question using your ideas

Comment: Although I was suspecting a question about the incompatibility of `array of string` (as the type for a local variable) and `TArray<string>` I  did not explicitly mention it. Updated the answer with that information.